# Is there a Difference between "logoff" and "shutdown -l" -command in Windows?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, shutdown, logoff

Is there a Difference between `logoff` and `shutdown -l` -command in Windows?
 They both logoff the current session.
(Background: i had a Problem where the software in the costumers remotesession (w2k12) didn't ran correctly until i logged of via logoff from command line.
The customer disconnects the session daily via a shortcut on the desktop, which starts a batch with the line `shutdown -l`)

Both are executables in system32-directory. 
Do they run different logoff-sequences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**They perform the same task**

They are simply different applications that perform the same task.  They both logoff a current session and close any applications that are associated with that session.

You asked.

> Do the run different logoff-sequences?

No, they initiate the same logoff sequence.